# PHP - Array change key names, keep values dynamically

Tags: php, laravel

I am loading data from an XML file and also trying to dynamically be able to match these values from the XML elements, in to my database table. **I am using Laravel 5.6**.

This is what I have now:

`config.php`:

```
'milestone' => [
     'columns'  => array(       
         "JobDept"                      => "department",
         "JobBranch"                    => "branch",
         "Destination"                  => "destination",
      ),
 ],
```

The above array have the following format, which maps my XML fle to my database columns:

```
"XML Element Name => Database Column Name"
```

So, I can now take the keys from above array (`JobDept, JobBranch, Destination`) and find these in my XML files:

```
$data = $xml->parse([
    'report' => ['uses' => 'item['.implode(",",$xmlFilters).']', 'default' => null]
]);
```

Above works just fine. This will populate the keys with actual values from my XML file:

```
0 => array:3 [▼
  "JobDept" => "FEA"
  "JobBranch" => "AAL"
  "Destination" => "TWTPE"
]
```

This is where I am stuck. Since my column names in my MySQL database is `department, branch, destination` I *guess* I need to change the array key names, to match my database column names, so the array will be like this:

```
0 => array:3 [▼
  "department" => "FEA"
  "branch" => "AAL"
  "destination" => "TWTPE"
]
```

Any idea on how to achieve this dynamically? As said, I am using Laravel 5.6 as a framework.

**Update:**
This is my `$data` array:

```
"report" => array:1[▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
          "JobDept" => "FEA"
          "JobBranch" => "AAL"
          "Destination" => "TWTPE"
        ]
 ]
```

Comment: Replace `key` with `milestone[columns][key]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example ([fiddle](https://3v4l.org/dHFkF)):

```
$array = [
    "JobDept" => "FEA",
    "JobBranch" => "AAL",
    "Destination" => "TWTPE",
];
$replace = [
    "JobDept"                      => "department",
    "JobBranch"                    => "branch",
    "Destination"                  => "destination",
];

$new_array = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $new_array[$replace[$k]] = $v;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: I have also created a fiddle here to demonstrate: [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/ObBh0)

Comment: And what? Iterate over `array[report]` if you need to replace keys in `report` subarray.

Comment: Still does not work. As soon as my `$array` gets more items, I get the `Undefined offset` error. See my updated **[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/F3Zao)**

Comment: Now `report` is `array of arrays` and you need two `foreach` loops. If you don;t know how to iterate over nested arrays that's another question, not what you ask originally.

Comment: Ah. Would you mind updating your answer to reflect the two foreach loop? Would be much appreciated.